# Hide "Site Settings" for specific users in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I have a user "membre1", I want to prevent him from accessing to site settings. I want it hidden for him, I'm one of the admins of the site, so I belive I'm able to do it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lB93b.png)